# Query for Elastic search aggregations based on nested array

Tags: java, elasticsearch, indexing, elasticsearch-5

I do have the documents like below in my index

```
{
      "bookName" : "coolbook",
      "timeStamp" : "2018-11-19T12:52:17.000Z",
      "referenceId" : "auth_test_01_01_000004",
      "peoplestatus" : [
        {
          "personId" : "p1",
          "status" : "like"
        },
        {
          "personId" : "p2",
          "status" : "dislike"
        },{
          "personId" : "p3",
          "status" : "netrual"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Now I want to query the aggregations of book count for person p1,p2 like below
the counts of books

1. p1-liked but p2-disliked
2. p1,p2 both liked
3. p2-disliked but p1-liked
4. p1,b2 both disliked

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is your query going to be for a specific P1 and P2, or are you trying to count all combinations where one person liked and another disliked?

Comment: I will be specifying two person ids in the query that i have to compare, and comparision is for all combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Since you require buckets with different filter for each bucket, [filters aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html) is best fit for this.
As per your comment there will be two person ids to be compared following is the query for your following two combinations:

- P1 liked but P2 disliked
- P1 and P2 both liked

```
    {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "aggs": {
        "books": {
          "filters": {
            "filters": {
              "P1L_P2DL": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "peoplestatus",
                        "query": {
                          "bool": {
                            "must": [
                              {
                                "bool": {
                                  "must": [
                                    {
                                      "term": {
                                        "peoplestatus.personId": "p1"
                                      }
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "term": {
                                        "peoplestatus.status": "like"
                                      }
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "peoplestatus",
                        "query": {
                          "bool": {
                            "must": [
                              {
                                "bool": {
                                  "must": [
                                    {
                                      "term": {
                                        "peoplestatus.personId": "p2"
                                      }
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "term": {
                                        "peoplestatus.status": "dislike"
                                      }
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "L1N3": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "peoplestatus",
                        "query": {
                          "bool": {
                            "must": [
                              {
                                "bool": {
                                  "must": [
                                    {
                                      "term": {
                                        "peoplestatus.personId": "p1"
                                      }
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "term": {
                                        "peoplestatus.status": "like"
                                      }
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "peoplestatus",
                        "query": {
                          "bool": {
                            "must": [
                              {
                                "bool": {
                                  "must": [
                                    {
                                      "term": {
                                        "peoplestatus.personId": "p2"
                                      }
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "term": {
                                        "peoplestatus.status": "like"
                                      }
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "size": 0
    }
```

Comment: Please note: I have added only two filters, you can add more for any number of combinations